# jquery:how to add css hover in with jquery css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover, jquery-1.9

I have set the hover opacity in my css,

```
.button-simple:hover {
    opacity:.70;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    filter: "alpha(opacity=70)";
}
```

But the hover opacity does not show after I have this line in my code,

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false).css({opacity:1,cursor:"pointer"});
```

Any idea what I can do to add the hover css in?

**EDIT:**

The reason I cannot use `!important` in my css is that I have this line to disable the submit button first,

```
$('input[type=submit]',parent).attr('disabled', true).css({opacity:0.4,cursor:"default"});
```

If I set `!important` in my css, this disabled button will the hover effect as well which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can avoid setting opacity with jquery, you should do this:

```
$('input[type=submit]',parent).attr('disabled', true).addClass("disabled");
.button-simple.disabled{
    opacity:.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=.4);
    filter: "alpha(opacity=.4)";
    cursor: default;
}

.button-simple{
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=1);
    filter: "alpha(opacity=1)";
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-simple.disabled:hover{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` to override the inline style jquery adds.

```
.button-simple:hover {
    opacity:.70 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70) !important;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=70)" !important;
}
```

Edit:

In light of the last edit an "elegant" solution would be:

```
.button-simple.active:hover {
    opacity:.70;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    filter: "alpha(opacity=70)";
}
```

And in your script where you are removing the disabled attribute add `.addClass('active')`.

Comment: If I set `!important` in my css, this disabled button will the hover effect as well which I don't want. Please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok easy fix, add a class to it and apply the hover, check my edit in 2 min.

Answer (score 1):

The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0. A lower value makes the element more transparent.

The value `opacity:1` makes it opaque.

Comment: The issue here is that jquery sets the styles applied via .css() inline, and they override the styles found in the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `button-simple` hover css like this using the [`!important rules`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules):

```
.button-simple:hover {
    opacity:.70 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70) !important;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=70)" !important;
}
```

Comment: If I set `!important` in my css, this disabled button will the hover effect as well which I don't want. Please see my edit above. thanks.